# Когда использовать  serialize(), а когда json_*-методы.

Tags: php

Привет.Меня интересует в каких случаях нужно использовать один и другой метод?Как я узнал что метод  serialize() можно проэктировать через __wakeup().Для обратного преобразования нужен исходный класс.Это все чем эти 2 способа отличаются?
Какой лучше по производительности?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

По возможности, лучше использовать `implode('|',$data)` - быстрее
По занимаемому месту json вроде лучше; Основное преимущество json перед serialize в том, что json поддерживают jscript и другие языки, а serialize - внутренний формат php.

Comment: Про поддержку в js совсем выпало с головы.Спасибо что напомнили.